# C - Segmentation fault with struct

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, stack

I'm really sorry if this is an easy-fix-question, but I'm a beginner.
I have an assignment to write some functions to a stack-struct. The struct was given. I can't get rid of the segmentation fault in push() line "s->elements..."
I don't know what is wrong after hours googling and searching.

Here the code:

```
#define STACK_SIZE 5
```

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct stackADT {
    int elements[STACK_SIZE];
    int count;
} stack;

void initialize(stack *s)
{
     stack *newStack;
     newStack = malloc(sizeof(*newStack));
     newStack->count = 0;

     s = newStack;
}

int push(stack *s, int value)
{
    if(s->count == 5) return -1;
    else {
        s->elements[s->count++] = value;
        return s->elements[s->count-1];
    }
}

int main()
{
    stack* sA;
    stack* sB;
    initialize(sA);
    initialize(sB);
    printf("%d\n",push(sA,3));
    return 0;
}

Comment: @Mirko Richter Why do you allocate an object of type stack dynamically? You could simply define a stack like  stack sA; Also function initialize initializes nothing.:)

Comment: OK. How can I change the function initialize to initialize something?;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you need something like the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STACK_SIZE  5

typedef struct stackADT 
{
    int elements[STACK_SIZE];
    int count;
} stack;

void initialize( stack *s )
{
    s->count = 0;
}

int push( stack *s, int value )
{
    return s->count == STACK_SIZE ? -1 : ( s->elements[s->count++] = value );
}

int main(void) 
{
    stack sA;
    stack sB;

    initialize( &sA );
    initialize( &sB );

    printf( "%d\n", push( &sA, 3 ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you're passing both pointers by value(so you're actually passing a copy of the pointer), change the initialize function to `int initilize(stack **s)` and `s = newStack;` to `*s = newStack;` then call initialize like this `initialize(&sA); initialize(&sB);`

You really shouldn't dynamically allocate objects unless you have to, also you're not `free()`ing the memory you allocated, that's a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks, This works! I get the part with the copy of the pointer. In the assignment the function initialize is defined as initialize(stack *s). Is it even possible to allocate memory like that?

Comment: @mikefedi I don't think so, must be a typo

Answer (score 2):

When you pass a pointer to a function, the function receives a **copy of the pointer**. This is generally fine, unless you are **changing/creating the START address** for the pointer.

In your case, `sA` and `sB` contain no address (they are pointers to nothing when you pass them to `initialize`). So your `initialize` function must take the **address of the pointer** rather than the **pointer itself** to assign an address to the pointer that will be visible in `main`. For example:

```
void initialize(stack **s)
{
    stack *newStack;
    newStack = malloc(sizeof(*newStack));
    newStack->count = 0;

    *s = newStack;
}

...

initialize (&sA);
```

Dereferencing the double pointer `**s` above, (e.g. `*s = newStack;`), assigns the address of `newStack` as the value for pointer `s`.

I would also suggesting checking that the allocation succeeded before assigning the location of `newStack` to `*s`:

```
void initialize(stack **s)
{
    stack *newStack;
    if (!(newStack = malloc(sizeof(*newStack)))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: memory allocation failed.\n", __func__);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    newStack->count = 0;

    *s = newStack;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are receiving a segmentation fault because you are attempting to assign a value in `push()` to an unallocated area of memory. `initialize()` works to successfully allocate memory and initialize it with `count = 0`, but your assignment of `s = newStack` does not work. As David and Alejandro pointed out, you are passing "a copy of the pointer." In essence, you are passing the address of the uninitialized `stack` variable, but you are not passing the function a way to update that variable with the new address. You need to pass it a pointer to the stack pointer. (Also known as a level two pointer.) This means `initialize()` will receive the memory address of the variable that holds the memory address of the stack structure. As such, the function can then assign the level two pointer's pointee the address to the malloced stack.

Perhaps that would be easier to understand by simply looking at the code:

```
#define STACK_SIZE 5

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct stackADT {
    int elements[STACK_SIZE];
    int count;
} stack;

void initialize(stack **s)
{
     stack *newStack;
     newStack = malloc(sizeof(*newStack));

     if(NULL == newStack){
        // Malloc could not allocate memory
        // for newStack.
        // Set s to NULL to indicate the error
        s = NULL;
        // Return prematurely
        return;
     } // else, malloc succeeded

     newStack->count = 0;

     // Assign the value of the malloced stack pointer to the pointee of stack **s
     *s = newStack;
}

int push(stack *s, int value)
{
    if( s->count == STACK_SIZE ){
        // Stack has too many elements.
        // Return with error value (-1)
        return -1;
    } else {
        // Assign the new value to the current last index
        s->elements[s->count] = value;
        // Add count to indicate a new variable has been added
        s->count++;
        // Use the array to return the value just added
        return s->elements[ (s->count - 1) ];
    }
}

int main()
{
    stack* sA;
    stack* sB;

    // Send the function a pointer to the stack pointer
    initialize(&sA);
    initialize(&sB);

    if(sA == NULL){
        puts("Could not allocate the memory for stack variable sA.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("%d\n", push(sA, 3) );

    // Clean up the memory
    free(sA);
    free(sB);

    return 0;
}
```

I have also modified the code slightly to split up the assignment of `value` in the `push()` function and I added a `malloc()` error check.

**Note**: *If you are comfortable with it, I would recommend using Vlad's push function. It's shorter and more concise; however, it sacrifices readability. As you are a beginner, I decided spreading it out might be easier to understand.*